# PHP+mySQL - won't update text field from PHP, but will update from adminer with same query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this php script:

```
$query = "UPDATE event_rsvp SET event_note = '" . $_POST[note] . "', event_rsvp_type_id = '" . $_POST[rsvpId] . "' WHERE user_id = '" . $_POST[userId] . "' AND event_id = '" . $_POST[eventId] . "'";   
$result = $mysqli->$query;
echo $query;
```

that echo gives me this:

```
UPDATE event_rsvp SET event_note = 'test', 
       event_rsvp_type_id = '4' 
WHERE user_id = '1' AND event_id = '1'
```

Problem is that only the event_rsvp_type_id is updated in database, event_note isn't.
However, if I copy this echo-ed query and paste it directly into adminer or phpmyadmin, it works fine and updates the note as expected.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that code will work _at all_. What is `$mysqli->$query` supposed to do?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says **[you are at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)**. Learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even **[escaping the string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)** is not safe! I recommend `PDO`, which I [wrote a function for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45514591) to make it extremely **easy**, very **clean**, and way more **secure** than using non-parameterized queries.

Comment: Well it certainly works in different scenarios.

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");

Comment: @user235937, but `$query` is a string. You can't do `$mysqli->"SELECT * FROM foo"`, and you can't do `$mysqli->$query` either.

Comment: Oh, right... thanks a lot, I kind of didn't notice that after 16 hours in front of PC... solved, working.

Comment: @user235937 I saw your post was edited, did my answer not help you?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE event_rsvp SET `event_note`=?, `event_rsvp_type_id`=? WHERE `user_id`=? AND `event_id`=?");
$query->bind_param("siii", $_POST['note'], $_POST['rsvpId'], $_POST['userId'], $_POST['eventId']);
$query->execute();
```

Your real problem is that you were missing the singlequotes on your variables, and also, `$mysqli->$query` doesn't make any sense, the `$query` part isn't a variable, it should just be `query`. I converted your code to use prepared statements as well, hopefully this will allow you to see how easy they are to use, while giving you **way** more security.